# Ridder's method advantage over other methods?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I can't find anywhere the advantages of using Ridder's method over any other numerical method. My professor said that it specializes in solving a unique set of functions, but I can't find anything about it anywhere.
When is Ridder's method more useful than something else and why?

I realize it may sound like a silly question but I have to answer it for a project.
Thanks!